# Is this a scenario to use delegates?

Tags: c#, delegates

I received a win-form application with following pseudo-code. Most of the current function codes are written in the code behind the forms as those functions interact with form controls.

1. loop through device connections
2. connect to a device
3. call a specific **function**, do some specific work
4. close the device connection

There are 10 different functions (entirely varied signatures from one another). First version of the application repeated step 1, 2, 4 for all the 10 functions. The second version optimized it by adding `select case` statement with numeric values to call the functions within device connection-loop.

However I feel that function delegates could improve this code.

But I am quite lost in making an analogue to the delegate concept with what I have in hand. Can I use delegates in this situation and how should I approach it in terms of the application execution/code design?

Answer (score 1):

it's hard to tell having only the pseudo-code but IMO you don't need a delegate - either use `Action<...>` or `Func<...>` depending on if you need a result or not.

For example it could look something like this:

```
static void DoForAllDevices(Action<Connection> action)
{
    foreach(var device in myDevices)
    {
        using (var connection = ConnectTo(device))
        {
            action(connection);
        } // typically Dispose will handle the closing
    }
}
```

then you just have to call it like this

```
DoForAllDevices(connection => myFirstFun(connection, additionalParameter);
```

now of course you can add all kind of exception-Handling, etc. inside `DoForAllDevices` - should be easy to do

Comment: Carsten Connection is a class name. `using (var connection = ConnectTo(device))` does this line mean, `ConnectionTo()` is a method from connection class?

Comment: you gave no code so I don't know anything about yours and this is just a example. Here `connection` is just a variable and the `using( ...)` line means that I use the `ConnectTo` device method of the current class (both of which **you** have to write for yourself) to connect to the `device` and give me a `connection` back. It just choose those names so that it is reasonable readable.